Home Insurance Non-Renewal impact for at risk home owners?
Trying to gauge the impact of insurance non-renewals on home owners. Let's say the person has a current loan and the insurance company decides during their next renewal cycle to not renew the home insurance for this person.
AI says these things:

If your homeowners insurance lapses, your mortgage lender will likely require you to purchase new coverage or buy a policy for you:
Force-placed insurance
If you don't get new coverage, your lender may purchase a policy for you, known as force-placed insurance. This policy will likely be
more expensive than your previous policy and may not cover your
personal property or liability. The cost of force-placed insurance may
be added to your monthly mortgage payments.
Penalties or fines
Some lenders may charge penalties or fines if you don't maintain adequate insurance. These penalties could be a percentage of your loan
balance or a flat fee.
Mortgage recall
In some cases, your lender may be able to recall your mortgage, requiring you to pay it back in full immediately. If you can't pay it
back, your lender may foreclose on your home.
To avoid these consequences, you should let your lender know if your policy is canceled or nonrenewed. You can also try to address any
issues that may have led to your policy being canceled. For example,
if your home is in a high-risk area, you could install hurricane
shutters or a metal roof. If you're having trouble getting approved
for coverage, you could consider a surplus lines insurer.

However I would like to know how much time will the lender grant the applicant to find new home insurance before they decide to either purchase insurance for the applicant(most likely at higher cost and with less coverage) or go through with other steps detailed above?
Thanks

This is generally detailed in the note. The lender can only enforce the contract you've agreed to.


However I would like to know how much time will the lender grant the
applicant to find new home insurance before they decide to either
purchase insurance for the applicant(most likely at higher cost and
with less coverage) or go through with other steps detailed above?

When you get the cancellation notice, contact the lender. They are also getting the notice, because the policy notes if there is mortgage. In some/many cases the policy is being paid from the escrow funds, so the company collecting the money each month and paying the insurance company will need to know about the change.
The mortgage paperwork may define the time period before the lender will force a policy they dictate. It is also possible that the  state defines these time periods.
If it isn't clear, ask the lender.

Loans generally require that you always have insurance. At the same time, lender-placed insurance is refundable by law if you have overlapping coverage.
Therefore, the requirement is you have uninterrupted coverage, but as long as this is accomplished, getting a new policy the day before the old one expires, or even retroactively (i.e. via a binder), you won't have to pay for force-placed insurance.
You will need to provide evidence to the loan servicer as soon as possible, and it can be a statement before the money works itself out.
12 CFR 1024.37(g)

(g) Cancellation of force-placed insurance. Within 15 days of receiving, from the borrower or otherwise, evidence demonstrating that the borrower has had in place hazard insurance coverage that complies with the loan contract's requirements to maintain hazard insurance, a servicer must:

(1) Cancel the force-placed insurance the servicer purchased to insure the borrower's property; and
(2) Refund to such borrower all force-placed insurance premium charges and related fees paid by such borrower for any period of overlapping insurance coverage and remove from the borrower's account all force-placed insurance charges and related fees for such period that the servicer has assessed to the borrower.


